# code using useParams, useEffect and useState hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Can someone please tell me the equivalent code using hooks for the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { match: { params } } = this.props;

  axios.get(`/api/users/${params.userId}`)
    .then(({ data: user }) => {
      console.log('user', user);

      this.setState({ user });
    });
}
```

---

Comment: i missed this line at the top ---componentDidMount() {
  const { match: { params } } = this.props; ---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact functionality to match your class component into a functional component with hooks would be the following:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const Component = () => {
   const { userId } = useParams();
   const [state, setState] = React.useState({ user: null });
   
   React.useEffect(() => {
      axios.get(`/api/users/${userId}`)
         .then(({ data: user }) => {
            console.log('user', user);
            setState({ user });
         });
   }, []);
}
```

`React.useEffect(() => {}, [])` with an empty dependency array essentially works the same way as the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.

The `React.useState` hook returns an array with the `state` and a method to update the state `setState`.

References:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

As an aside, and pointed out by @Yoshi:

The snippet provided is error prone, and the "moving to hooks" snippet will have the same errors that occur in the example. For example, as the request is in `componentDidMount`, if the `userId` changes it won't trigger a fetch to get the user data for the userId. To ensure this works in the hook, all you need to do is provide the `userId` in the dependency array in the `useEffect`...

```
   const latestRequest = React.useRef(null);
  
   React.useEffect(() => {
      latestRequest.current = userId;

      axios.get(`/api/users/${userId}`)
         .then(({ data: user }) => {
            if (latestRequest.current == userId) {
               setState({ user });
            }
         });
   }, [userId]);
```

Comment: I think the effect requires the `userId` as a dependency.

Comment: If we're going off the OP's question, we can see it's being called in `componentDidMount`, if we put `userId` as a dependency, it'd match more if the prop were to update to refetch.

Comment: True, but as it stands this would trigger the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` lint rule. Also I think it's an error, if the url changes and includes a new userId, surely the effect should rerun?

Comment: You're right in an error-prone application, it should rerun on a new `userId`, as well as use `useRef` and a `unmount` return function to ensure reruns of the `useEffect` doesn't update the state with stale data. But their question was specifically how they'd achieve their code in hooks.

Comment: Ok, I yield ;) But maybe add it as a point of caution to your answer?

Comment: You're right, it should be added, it's a bit of a footgun with hooks, especially with asynchronous requests!